# Passing Object to directive through attribute and containing variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wanna transfer a `$scope.data` to directive through its attribute in a Object, Can I achieve below format with any solution but not through separated attribute?

```
<custom-directive detail="{index:1, data: {{data}}}">
</custom-directive>
```

And the scope is set to below in directive

```
scope: {detail: "="}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be

```
return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        model: '=ngModel',
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
           if (!ngModel) {
              return;
           }

           console.log(scope.model); // your passed data
      }
}
```

and then

```
<custom-directive ngModel="data"></custom-directive>
```

Now you will have your `$scope.data` passed to the directive inside `scope.model`. But note that, any change in `scope.model` in directive will reflect in `$scope.data` too.

To avoid that, you can simpley change `ngModel`.

```
return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
            data: '=myData',
          },
          link: function(scope, element, attributes) {

               console.log(scope.data); // your passed data
          }
    }
```

and then

```
<custom-directive my-data="data"></custom-directive>
```

Answer (score 0):

You still have the solution to create your object in your controller :

```
$scope.detail = {index:1, data:$scope.data};
```

and to give it to your directive :

```
<custom-directive detail="detail"></custom-directive>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just write data only in your object, it will automatically resolves from your controller. Do as below:

**HTML**

```
<custom-directive detail="{index:1, data: data}">
</custom-directive>
```

**Directive**

```
myApp.directive('customDirective', function() {
   return {
       restrict:"AE",
    scope:{
        detail:"="
    },
    link:function(scope,ele,attrs) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(scope.detail));
    }
   }
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20548/)

Comment: It works but I got error in console, codes can't do the next job after that, why?

Comment: That error should be related to diff code. This code will not effect to others.